# DataTables ajax.reload() loses page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables. After ajax request, I call `the ajax.reload()` method to refresh my dataTable but I lose the current page. It returns the first page.

Here is my DataTables init:

```
datatable_appointments = $('#datatable_appointments').DataTable({
    "responsive" : true,
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "bSort" : false,
    "ajax": function(data, callback, settings) {
        // make a regular ajax request using data.start and data.length
        $.get(URL_API + URL_APPOINTMENTS_STATE + '/', {
            limit: data.length,
            offset: data.start,
            search: data.search.value
        }, function(res) {
            if (res.error) {
                callback({
                    recordsTotal: 0,
                    recordsFiltered: 0,
                    data : ""
                });
            } else {
                data_appointments = res.data;
                // map your server's response to the DataTables format and pass it to
                // DataTables' callback
                callback({
                    recordsTotal: res.total_data,
                    recordsFiltered: res.total_data,
                    data: res.data
                });
                $("#datatable_appointments > tbody > tr > td").addClass("text-center");
                $("#datatable_appointments > tbody > tr > td").css("vertical-align", "middle");
                $("#datatable_appointments > thead > tr > th").addClass("text-center");
            }
        });
    },
    "columns" : [
        { "data": "service_name"},
        { "data": "doctor_info"},
        { "data": "patient_name", render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return row.name + " " + row.surname;
        }},
        { "data": "appointment_date", render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            var formattedDate = new Date(row.appointment_date);
            var day = formattedDate.getDate();
            var month =  formattedDate.getMonth();
            var hours = (formattedDate.getHours().toString().length == 1) ? '0' + formattedDate.getHours() : formattedDate.getHours();
            hours += ':';
            hours += (formattedDate.getMinutes().toString().length == 1) ? formattedDate.getMinutes() + '0' : formattedDate.getMinutes();
            return day + ' ' + months[month] + ', ' + hours;
        }},
        { "data": "state", render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            if (row.state == '0')
                return '<i class="fa fa-circle font-red-mint"></i><br />İptal';
            else if (row.state == '1')
                return '<i class="fa fa-circle font-green-jungle"></i><br />Onaylı';
            else if (row.state == '2')
                return '<i class="fa fa-circle font-grey-salsa"></i><br />Beklemede';
        }},
        { "data": "actions", render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            if (row.state == '2')
                return '<div class="btn-group btn-group-circle">' +
                            '<button type="button" onclick="setState(\''+row.id+'\', \'1\');" class="btn btn-outline green btn-sm">Onayla</button>' +
                            '<button type="button" onclick="setState(\''+row.id+'\', \'0\');" class="btn btn-outline red btn-sm">İptal Et</button>' +
                        '</div>';
            else
                return '';
        }}
    ],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "Kayıt bulunamadı.",
        "sZeroRecords": "Bu kriterde sonuç bulunamadı.",
        "search": "Bul",
        "sProcessing" : "<img src='/assets/global/img/loading-spinner-blue.gif' />",
        "sInfo": "Toplam <b>_TOTAL_</b> veri bulunmaktadır.",
        "sLengthMenu": "Gösterilen kayıt sayısı _MENU_",
        "sInfoFiltered": "",
        "sInfoEmpty":"",
        "paginate": {
            "sPrevious": "Önceki",
            "sNext": "Sonraki",
            "sFirst" : "İlk",
            "sLast" : "Son"
        }

    }
});
```

And my `setState` method in same js file:

```
function setState(id, state) {
    $.ajax({
        url : URL_API + URL_APPOINTMENTS_STATE + '/' + id,
        type : 'put',
        data : {'state' : state},
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (response) {
            if (response.error) {

            } else {
                datatable_appointments.ajax.reload();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to pass parameters for keeping current page like:

```
datatable_appointments.ajax.reload( null, false )
```

source: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: Hi there! This does work but the problem we have is that if we have for example 3 pages, then we delete all elements in the 3rd page and refresh, dataTables will display the 3rd empty page even if now the sum of pages is 2.

Answer (score 9):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table_id').DataTable( {
            stateSave: true
        } );
    });
```

Anyone who are using jQuery DataTables and wants to perform tasks e.g. reload the page, or edit, delete, will face a problem to lose the current page and navigate to 1st page, this snippet will help him to stay on the same page, It avoids to return from current page to first page.

Comment: savestate should be between ", "stateSave": true